# Problems with BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I am making a game (like Civilization) that has different tile types that I want to render as images. I have 9 different 16x16 png images to load in (called Con1, Con2, etc.), and here is my image loading code: (img[] is my BufferedImage array)

```
public void loadImages(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            try {
                img[i] = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Con"+i+".png"));
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Missing Image");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I then paint these images with this code: (t[][] is my tile type array)

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(loop){
            BufferedImage B = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics r = B.getGraphics();
            for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++){
                    if(i[x][y] == 0){
                        if (t[x][y] == 0){
                            g.drawImage(img[0], x, y, this);
                        }
                        else if(t[x][y] == 1){
                            g.drawImage(img[1], x, y, this);
                        }
                        else if(t[x][y] == 3){
                            g.drawImage(img[3], x, y, this);
                        }
                        else if(t[x][y] == 4){
                            g.drawImage(img[4], x, y, this);
                        }
                        else if(t[x][y] == 5){
                            g.drawImage(img[5], x, y, this);
                        }
                    }
                    r.fillRect(x*SCALE, y*SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
                }
            }

            g.drawImage(B, 0, 22, this);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that it doesn't show up correctly when I run it. I get this image:

[image]

that flashes on and off in the top-left corner of the window. What I am supposed to see is an image similar to the top-left portion of the above one (landmasses surrounded by ocean) except large enough to fill the window. Here is some runnable code: (I don't think the code will run without the required images but I would appreciate some help with getting the images to you all.)

```
//imports
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MCVCon extends JFrame implements KeyListener, MouseListener{
    //setting up variables
    public BufferedImage[] img = new BufferedImage[9];
    private final int WIDTH = 50, HEIGHT = 50;
    private boolean loop = false;
    private int SCALE = 16;
    int t[][] = new int[WIDTH][HEIGHT]; //terrain type (since I took out the terrain generation it is set to 0 or ocean)
    public MCVCon(){
        //creating the window
        super("Conqueror");
        setSize(SCALE*WIDTH, SCALE*HEIGHT+22);
        setVisible(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        loadImages();
        loop = true;
        while(true){
            this.repaint();
            //delay for repaint
            try{
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //load images
    public void loadImages(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            try {
                img[i] = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Con"+i+".png"));
            }catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Missing Image");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    //paint the images
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(loop){
            BufferedImage B = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics r = B.getGraphics();
            for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++){
                    if (t[x][y] == 0){
                        g.drawImage(img[0], x, y, this);
                    }
                    else if(t[x][y] == 1){
                        g.drawImage(img[1], x, y, this);
                    }
                    r.fillRect(x*SCALE, y*SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
                }
            }

            g.drawImage(B, 0, 22, this);
        }
    }
    //run the program
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MCVCon();
    }
    //necessary overrides
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

I was wondering what the problem might be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a scaling factor in there, but hard to say without more information, especially what the original images look like. Side note -- you're not doing this drawing within an active painting method, such as a JPanel's `paintComponent` method, are you? If so, it is woefully inefficient.

Comment: Also for better help, create and post a valid [mcve], a ***small*** but complete demo program that we can compile and run ourselves. Please read the link.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not using the paintComponent method, I am using a JFrame and just drawing a rectangle for each pixel, and on the topic, I have a SCALE final variable for the pixel graphics, but I do not know how to scale up the images I loaded in. Could you explain how to do that or link me to an example?

Comment: Please improve the question first, including creating (and yes you'll need to create a new program for the question) and showing your [mcve]. Let's make the question more answerable and more helpful to future visitors as well.

Comment: And you sound like you're not doing Swing painting to its best advantage if you're drawing directly on a JFrame.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am working on the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example but I was wondering how others would compile and run the program without the necessary images.

Comment: A side note about exception handling:  You don’t really want your game to run if you can’t load all of the images, do you?  If an image fails to load, either there’s a coding mistake or the application was packaged incorrectly.  Either way, the correct course of action is to exit with a fatal error, because it doesn’t make sense to continue without those images.

Comment: @VGR Ok I will try that. That's a good idea.

Comment: It's almost an MVC, but it relies on images, specifically, `"Con"+i+".png"`, images that we currently don't have.

Comment: Also you're using a dangerous animation loop, the `while (true)` loop with `Thread.sleep`, something guaranteed to fail, once you launch the GUI correctly on the Swing event thread.

Comment: And I was correct, you are doing your graphics incorrectly, drawing directly in the JFrame's paint method, not calling the super's method, doing heavy-duty code within a painting method.

Comment: Please help us with the images somehow. And get rid of the KeyListener/MouseListener code which is unnecessary for the problem at hand and only serves to distract. Remember that this program should be ***minimal***.

Comment: Also, where do you make your `t` int array into anything other than a default array of 0's?

Comment: 1. You're not clearing the `BufferedImage`, so it could be leaving artifacts from the previous paint loop; 2. `JFrame` isn't double buffered, while you're using a `BufferedImage`, there are better solutions which would prevent a number of other issues associated with overriding `paint` of `JFrame`; 3. Avoid `KeyListener`, it's always a poor choice, instead, maybe have a look at the key bindings API

Comment: *"I have a SCALE final variable for the pixel graphics, but I do not know how to scale up the images I loaded in"* - You could scale the `Graphics` context or use a `AffineTransform`, plenty of examples abound

Comment: `SCALE*HEIGHT+22` looks like you're trying to compensate for the title bar of the frame, which is a bad idea and yet another reason why you shouldn't try painting directly to a frame

Comment: `g.drawImage(img[1], x, y, this);` isn't painting to the `BufferedImage`, but is painting directly to the component's `Graphics` context, but then you can draw the buffered image over the top, so I've got no idea what's going on :P

Comment: You also have no conversion from a virtual world to the physical world, meaning that `t[x][y]` does not map to `x` and `y` on the screen, because the tile has `width` and `height` associated with it

Comment: Exactly -- the scale factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I had a look at your code, there's no easy way to say, but it's a mess, with compounding issues which would make it very difficult to isolate the origin of any one problem, other than to say, they all feed into each other.

Let's start with the painting...

You're painting directly to the frame. This is generally discouraged for a number of reasons.

Let's start with the fact that `JFrame` isn't a single component, it's made up of a number compounding components

[image: JRootPane]

This makes it inherently dangerous to paint directly to, as any one of the child components could be painted without the frame's `paint` method been called.

Painting directly to a frame also means you're painting without consideration to the frame's borders/decorations, which are added into the visible area of the window, but wait...

```
setSize(SCALE*WIDTH, SCALE*HEIGHT+22);
```

suggests that you've tried to compensate for this, but this is "guess" work, as the decorations could take up more or less space depending on the configuration of the system

And, finally, top level containers aren't actually double buffered.

"But I'm painting to my own buffer" you say - but you're not

You create a `BufferdImage` and assign it's `Graphics` context t `r`

```
BufferedImage B = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics r = B.getGraphics();
```

But when you paint anything, you're using `g`, which is the `Graphics` context passed to the `paint` method

```
g.drawImage(img[0], x, y, this);
```

This is also woefully inefficient, as you're creating a new `BufferedImage` each time `paint` is called, which takes time to create, takes up memory and puts extra strain on the garbage collection process as the local object becomes eligible for disposal almost immediately

Don't even get me started on the "main paint loop"

The next problem you have, is you have no concept of virtual and real world space.

You make a virtual map of your world using `t`, which maintains information about which tile should be used for a given x/y coordinate, but you never map this to the real world, instead, you paint each tile exactly at the same pixel x/y position, which means they now overlap, tiles have width and height, which means they need to be offset when painted onto the real world.

And finally, which I think is your actually question, is about scaling.  There are a number of ways you could apply scaling, you could pre-scale the tiles when you load them, this gives you a lot of control over "how" they are scaled, but locks you into a single scale.

You could instead maintain a list of the scaled tiles, generated from a master list, which can be updated if the scale changes

Or you could simply scale the `Graphics` context directly.

Now, I've create a simple example, based on your code, correcting for most of the above.  It creates a series of randomly colored rectangles at 10x10 pixels, instead of tiles, but the concept is the same.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MCVCon extends JFrame {
    //setting up variables

    public MCVCon() {
        //creating the window
        super("Conqueror");
        add(new GamePane());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MCVCon frame = new MCVCon();
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    //necessary overrides

    public class GamePane extends JPanel {

        public BufferedImage[] img = new BufferedImage[9];
        private final int width = 5, height = 5;
        private int scale = 16;
        int t[][] = new int[width][height]; //terrain type (since I took out the terrain generation it is set to 0 or ocean)
        Color[] colors = new Color[]{
            Color.RED,
            Color.BLUE,
            Color.CYAN,
            Color.DARK_GRAY,
            Color.GRAY,
            Color.GREEN,
            Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
            Color.MAGENTA,
            Color.ORANGE,
            Color.PINK,
            Color.YELLOW
        };
        int tileHeight = 10;
        int tileWidth = 10;

        public GamePane() {
            loadImages();

            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                    int value = rnd.nextInt(9);
                    System.out.println(value + "- " + colors[value]);
                    t[x][y] = value;
                }
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width * tileWidth * scale, height * tileHeight * scale);
        }

        public void loadImages() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                try {
                    img[i] = new BufferedImage(tileWidth, tileHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    Graphics2D g2d = img[i].createGraphics();
                    g2d.setColor(colors[i]);
                    g2d.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight));
                    g2d.dispose();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Missing Image");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    g2d.drawImage(img[t[x][y]], x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight, this);
                }
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I really appreciate the insightful comments.

Comment: I tried out your code and it worked perfectly! I really appreciate the help, and I can finally continue with the project. Many thanks.

Comment: So i was working on the code and I had some difficulty with an "update" function I had originally that was called in a while(true) loop; however, I can't quite figure out where to put that loop. I tried putting it in the main class but I realized that because the update method is in a different class. I was wondering if you knew a solution to this.

Comment: The `Timer` is now acting as the "main loop" - see [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details